# Apache Http Client timout issue

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have this part of code:

```
         RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000)
                        .setSocketTimeout(30 * 1000)
                        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30 * 1000)
                        .build();

         BotSynch.httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

         httpClient.execute(post);
```

the BotSynch.HttpClient is a class field

```
private static CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
```

The post in the last line is a HttpPost.

My implementation so far works well, but if the Server I am connected to, doesn't answer to a post request in 30 seconds nothing is happening.

Sometimes it can take up to 10 minutes until I receive the answer from the server to the request and that is actually what I tried to prevent with the timeout setting above.

Is there something I missed here or something that should be handled beside this settings?

Comment: Is this  `BotSynch.httpClient` a correct definition? Have you tried defining the `httpClient` as `CloseableHttpClient`?

Comment: sorry i added this for clarity in my question. Its already a CloseableHttpClient, yes.

Comment: Please note that as far as socket timeout is concerned if the server sends at least one packet every 30 seconds the connection will not trigger a socket timeout.

Comment: Mhm okay. What would be a workaround if the connection keeps alive due to that? So far I know I cannot disconnect because of to less packets per 30 seconds right?

Comment: There is no work-around because there is nothing to work around. This is how timeouts are supposed to work. You might consider reducing the timeout value to, say, 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expected behavior is that the `HttpClient#execute` call should never take longer than 30 seconds, regardless of the execution result, you should consider using the `HttpUriRequest#abort` method in a background thread method that could abort the request after the specified interval.

```
    final HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = ...
    executorService.schedule(request::abort, (long)30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

We (myself included) should never forget that this is not what the `socketTimeout` does.